# Apollo boost trigger refetch outside of component

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo

I'm playing around with Apollo's new [apollo-boost](https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/zero-config-graphql-state-management-27b1f1b3c2c3) in React (web) and I'm wondering about two things: a) why doesn't Apollo automatically refetches data on variable changes and b) how can refetch be called outside of the `Query` component?

In my specific use case, I need to pass certain filters from the parent component's state. Consider the following code:

```
class GalleryPage extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super();
    this.state = {
      filters:           {
        brands:    [1, 3],
        filetypes: [4, 5, 6],
      },
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Query query={FilesQuery} variables={this.state.filters}>
          {result => (result.networkStatus === 7 ? result.data.files.map(file => <div>{file.name}</div>) : '')}
        </Query>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

When `this.state.filters` is changed, I would expect Apollo to refetch the data. But since this is not working, I'm trying to call `refetch`. I'm able to call `refetch` by destructuring it from data and calling it like: `<button type="button" onClick={() => refetch()}>Refetch</button>`. Obviously, this won't work outside of the component. And I don't know how to call it outside of the component. I feel like an event system might be of help here, but I'm unsure whether that is the right way to go.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in the example code seems to be that nested objects do not seem to trigger the refetch. So, what I did to still trigger a refetch, is change the organisation of the state:

```
// Instead of
this.state = {
  filters: {
    brands: [1, 3],
    filetypes: [4, 5, 6],
  }
}

// I'm now doing
this.state =  {
  filteredBrands: [1, 3],
  filteredFiletypes: [4, 5, 6]
}
```